# footnote line not disappearing

Tags: footnotes, footer

I have made a document with XeTeX. Initially, I added a footnote but later removed it. But the footnote separator line is not disappearing. Why is this so?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruj6O.png]

**EDIT:** Added MWE

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\newcommand{\rom}{\itshape}%\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\section*{\emph{pa-varga} --  Labial sound\protect\footnote{pronounced with the lips}}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
 \textbf{English} & \textbf{Pronunciation}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
{\rom pa} & as in \textbf{p}ill\tabularnewline
{\rom pha} & as in scoo\textbf{p-h}oney\tabularnewline
{\rom ba} & as in \textbf{b}ut,  \textbf{b}ank\tabularnewline
{\rom bha} & as in a\textbf{bh}or, tu\textbf{b-h}ard\tabularnewline
{\rom ma} & as in \textbf{m}ice,  \textbf{m}oney\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you have not shown any, how do you expect someone to help you except by trying to guess what you have done. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done.

Comment: @PeterWilson Yes, I am aware that a MWE is necessary. I have asked, in the past, quite a few questions on TeX.SE, But I wasn't able to reproduce the issue that I am facing with this document in the MWE. That's why I couldn't post a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find what caused the problem.
But I managed to find a solution, sort of.

What I did was to completely re-jig the lower part of the page [change its contents etc.] and that removed the empty footer area.